# Revove local admin but NOT Domain admin

Tags: powershell

Using this script to remove all local admins from each computer however it also removes domain admins is there a way to do this without removing domain administrators?

```
$remove = net localgroup administrators |
          select -skip 6 |
          ? {$_ -and $_ -notmatch 'successfully|^administrator$'};
foreach ($user in $remove) {
    net localgroup administrators "`"$user`"" /delete
};
```

Comment: Enumerate local users and check which one is in the local administrators group. And use Powershell commandlets instead of `net`.

Comment: what do u mean by powershell commandlets? please provide example

Comment: See my and @boxdog's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
Get-LocalGroupMember administrators | 
   Where {$_.name -like "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\*" -and $_.objectclass -eq "User"} | 
      Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators'
```

To make it more locale independent you could use SID `S-1-5-32-544` instead of a group name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' | 
    Where-Object Name -notlike '*Domain Admins' |
        Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators'
```